# wsl still not recognized after enabled in dism

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I apologize if this was posted, I did go through a number of posts first.

I am attempting to run a linux VM on my desktop using WSL 2, however I continuously get the error: "'wsl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I have enabled it multiple times using the command dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart in an elevated CMD.

Note: I am using the Microsoft Insiders Dev mode on my computer. I configured it today and did restart to settle the update.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like you need to enable wsl from Windows Features.

> Click Windows > Search "Turn Windows features on or off" > Open the
> list of features > Select "Windows Subsystem for Linux", enable it and
> restart

It is recommended to enable "Virtual Machine Platform" and "Hyper-V" as well.
Please refer to the image below.[image]

Comment: My problem was turnd off "Hyper-v". Thank you for advice!